# Using an os path in Tkinter PhotoImage

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a program that will display images on a Tkinter canvas, but I need to use images in a different folder than the program is in so I can't use what I usually do:
`img = PhotoImage(file=some_img)`

I have an os path like C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\some_img. I need to access some_img to make it a PhotoImage while it is in a different folder. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the full path then that should work fine as it is.

Comment: I tried this: `img = PhotoImage(file=img_os_path)` and put it on the canvas, but it didn't appear.